# Joining Potentially Empty Data Frames in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have four dataframes that come from four csvs to join into one final dataframe in Spark, all with set schemas. However, sometimes only 1-3 dataframes pass through, but they still will be joined into the final dataframe, with the missing values from the missing/empty dataframes as null. What would be the best approach to do this? I tried doing outer joins, but the problem is I can't join on empty dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the dataframe is empty by 
df.rdd.isEmpty

and if you find it to be empty do a left outer join